# Spotipy has no .devices() method?

Tags: python, spotipy

This is kinda weird. I tried a method from the readthedocs, but it just says that there is an attribute error.

```
AttributeError: 'Spotify' object has no attribute 'devices'
```

The code is as follows:

```
import spotipy.util as util 
import spotipy
(token left out for security reasons)
sp = spotipy.client.Spotify(auth=token)
sp.trace = True
sp.trace_out = True

print(sp.devices())
```

Comment: hmm that's weird, it is in the docs, also checked out the source code and it's there as well, takes no arguments and should return a `GET` on the `me/devices` endpoint. are you using the newest version of the library?

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped me figure out what was wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

This is rather odd.

Turns out the version installed by pip, although it says it's the latest version, it isn't.

Downloaded the latest version from the Github, and put it in my project workspace. Works great!